# How to make CodeNarc force maven build to fail

Tags: maven, groovy, codenarc

I'm trying to integrate CodeNarc into a maven based project and I've been running into problems.
I want to use a custom ruleset, and when a rule is violated, I'd like my maven build to fail.

How can I configure codenarc so that violations of rules lead to a failure when I run the following?

```
mvn clean install
```

Also, the documentation for configuring CodeNarc in a POM doesn't explain how to reference where my custom ruleset is. Any advice for how to set that up? Thanks!

When I run mvn clean install with the configurations below (I have a groovy file with blatant violations in accordance with my ruleset)

My build succeeds. :(

I tried referencing my own ruleset and no violations were being produced.
I took away a rulesetfiles property in the POM and it started producing violations.
(But I don't get to choose my own)

Anyone know how to make it actually read a custom rule set file? I tried with both xml and groovy.

Here's my ruleset and plugin config from my POM:

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0"; 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0 http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd";
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd">;

    <description>Dummy rule set</description>

    <rule class='org.codenarc.rule.formatting.SpaceAfterIf'>
        <property name='priority' value='1'/>
    </rule>

    <rule class='org.codenarc.rule.basic.EmptyIfStatement'>
        <property name='priority' value='1'/>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

I referenced this ruleset in my POM like this:

> ```
> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
> <artifactId>codenarc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>0.18-1</version>
> <configuration>
>     <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/groovy</sourceDirectory>
>     <maxPriority1Violations>0</maxPriority1Violations>
>     <maxPriority2Violations>0</maxPriority2Violations>
>     <maxPriority3Violations>0</maxPriority3Violations>
>     <rulesetfiles>${basedir}/rulesets/ruleset.xml</rulesetfiles>
>     <xmlOutputDirectory>${basedir}/</xmlOutputDirectory>
> </configuration>
> <executions>
>     <execution>
>         <id>execution1</id>
>         <phase>install</phase>
>         <goals>
>             <goal>codenarc</goal>
>         </goals>
>     </execution>
> </executions>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same some time ago. I remember it was possible to run with maven properly but I don't have this config. Why? Because CodeNarc needs to compile your sources for purpuse of some rules execution. But codenarc maven plugin doesn't pass classpath and compilation was failing.

So I went for different approach which is running CodeNarc as a test source with ant task. It looks like:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class GroovyCodeNarcStaticAnalysisRunner extends Specification {

    private static final GROOVY_FILES = '**/*.groovy'
    private static final ANALYSIS_SCOPE = 'src/main/groovy'
    private static final RULESET_LOCATION = 'file:tools/static-analysis/codenarc.xml'
    private static final HTML_REPORT_FILE = 'target/codenarc-result.html'
    private static final XML_REPORT_FILE = 'target/codenarc-result.xml'

    def 'Groovy code should meet coding standards'() {
        given:
        def ant = new AntBuilder()
        ant.taskdef(name: 'codenarc', classname: 'org.codenarc.ant.CodeNarcTask')

        expect:
        ant.codenarc(
                ruleSetFiles: RULESET_LOCATION,
                maxPriority1Violations: 0,
                maxPriority2Violations: 0,
                maxPriority3Violations: 0)
                {
                    fileset(dir: ANALYSIS_SCOPE) {
                        include(name: GROOVY_FILES)
                    }
                    report(type: 'text') {
                        option(name: 'writeToStandardOut', value: true)
                    }
                    report(type: 'xml') {
                        option(name: 'outputFile', value: XML_REPORT_FILE)
                    }
                    report(type: 'html') {
                        option(name: 'outputFile', value: HTML_REPORT_FILE)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

You don't need to use Spock's `Specification` for that. Any test runner will do. On the maven side it's enough to make CodeNarc dependency configured with scope *test*.

Comment: So it's impossible to get codenarc running with a custom ruleset as a maven plugin?

Comment: As far as I remember it was possible for me, but some of _Enhanced rules_ failing because CodeNarc maven plugin wasn't passing classpath jars. It may be fixed till now though. The rest of the rules was working fine.

Comment: Were you referencing your custom ruelset fie the same way I am? Because it's getting completely ignored as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember. It was quite time ago. What I can spot is you're wiring CodeNarc quite late, at install. It should've happen at early build phase. I don't see why it wouldn't work though. Maybe custom ruleset path or the file itself is invalid?

Comment: I tried using the test build phase to the same effect. 

I also tried a literal file path to the xml.

Comment: I'm not able to even run the configuration from your example. This is what's happening: [java] ERROR: Invalid argument format: [Maven]. Expression: matcher. Values: matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=\-(.*)
\=(.*) region=0,5 lastmatch=]
However I have found equivalent of the example from my answer with the difference that CodenNarc Ant task is run by Maven plugin. This should do the job for you: https://github.com/ozone-development/owf8-ozoneplatform/blob/master/pom.xml (line 466).

Comment: The last thing which comes to my mind is that according to the  example usages of the plugin have this set like `<rulesetfiles>rulesets/basic.xml,rulesets/braces.xml,rulesets/concurrency.xml,...</rulesetfiles>` which are predefined rulesets included in the CodeNarc jar file. Thus why maybe this param expect classpath to be provided, not file path. If the plugin works for you (for me it doesn't) and you don't like run it with ant plugin (which I recommend), try putting  your rules file on a classpath (f.g. in resources folder) and refer to it as such.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out both things today.

Comment: I'm trying the ant plugin, and it's complaining that my ruleset xml is either inaccessible or doesn't exist. Is there a particular way I should be referencing it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using classpath rather than file path, how would I go about setting that up and then referencing it?

Comment: That's from [CodeNarc page](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-creating-ruleset.html): _The Groovy RuleSet file itself must be accessible on the classpath._ I suppose with xml it's the same. If you like to know about maven and classpaths here it is [relevant page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html). I haven't used maven for longer time now but probably if you put your rules in src/test/resources/something/rules.xml and then pass _test classpath_ to ant task you'll be able to refer it as `something/rules.xml`

Comment: You may still try to go back to your 1st approach. It seems it might not work because of referring rules as file instead of classpath resource. I'm not sure how the codenarc plugin resolves classpath though. As I mentioned previously, like a year ago I'd tried to use it but dropped this idea exactly because of classpath issues. [One more link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953377/classpath-problemsrunning-ant-java-task-with-maven-antrun-plugin) which may help for the ant task approach.

Comment: Still seeing that my ruleset file is inaccessible :(

Comment: Good news: I got it to recognize my file by putting "file:" in front of the path. However, not it's complaining that it can't find the classes of the rules I'm using.

Comment: Bounty awarded! My main problem (being able to use a custom ruleset) was solved. Now I just need to figure out why it only recognizes some rules and not others. I get ClassNotFoundException when uses particular rules like EmptyIfStatement.

Comment: How new the rule is compared to CodeNarc version you are using? Maybe try using the newest CodeNarc version (0.21 I suppose). By default maven plugin is using much older version of the CodeNarc. That's probably not the case though now as you've stopped using codenarc maven plugin.

Comment: I think I just got the names of the rules wrong, it's working now.